# Trigger MYSQL con multiples UPDATES

Tags: mysql, trigger

Amablemente solicito de su colaboración con el siguiente trigger de MySql.

```
UPDATE ventas SET fecha = now()  WHERE estado='Vigente';
UPDATE ventas SET update = "system"  WHERE estado='Cancelado';
```

El trigger funciona, 
pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer algo asi:

```
UPDATE ventas SET fecha = now()  WHERE estado='Vigente', 
              SET update = "system"  WHERE estado='Cancelado';
```

Lo anterior es dado que en la tabla de ventas tengo un tigger Before Update, y quiero hacer una sola actualización a la linea, y no dos como está pasando.

Muchas gracias

Comment: yo en todo tu código no veo donde esta declarándose la estructura `TRIGGER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor es que hagas algo así:

```
UPDATE ventas 
SET fecha  = CASE WHEN estado='Vigente' THEN now()  ELSE fecha END, 
    update = CASE WHEN estado='Cancelado' THEN "system"  ELSE update END
WHERE estado IN ('Vigente', 'Cancelado');
```

No estoy seguro de si funcionará a la primera en MySQL porque you suelo usar MS-SQL Server pero debería ser algo así.

Ah, me imagino que limitarás los registros que se van a actualizar teniendo en cuenta las tablas virtuales Inserted y Deleted porque sino... cada vez actualizas la tabla ventas entera.

Comment: Muchas gracias!
fue solo pegarle el el codigo tal cual funcionó a la primera.
Se va a actualizar la tabla completa, se espera unos 20.000 registros, 
pero eso se ha venido haciendo, solo que hacia 2 update, y cada update disparaba un nuevo trigger en la tabla ventas, pero así lo tienen funcionando, puede haber una mejor practica.

Comment: Perfecto Ruben !!! Si mi respuesta ha sido la que ha resuelto tu problema recuerda votarla y marcarla como "la respuesta correcta".